# Error attempting to use rJava from a web application

Tags: r, rjava, rapache

I am using R version 2.15.2 on Ubuntu 11.04. `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_21.
```

To be able to use load `rJava` from R I have to set `JAVA_HOME` to `$JAVA_HOME/jre`.
However, I am unable to use `rJava` from an R script invoked by an R web application.
I have set `JAVA_HOME` to  `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_21/jre` in `envvars` but this trick does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to expand on "I am unable to use rJava" - like showing us example code and most importantly **error messages**.

Comment: Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

Comment: If I do export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_21/jre loading rJava works fine. This is not the case, however, when using the R script through a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to deactivate JAVA_HOME within your R-session with the following code before loading rJava:

```
if (Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="")
  Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")
library(rJava)
```

What is the result then?